# Justify text in show hide div with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, justify

I have a function to show/hide text and it works fine. I have two issues, however:

1. I cannot justify the text although I have specified this property in my CSS and in the JavaScript.
2. I cannot get rid of the line break when displaying the text. I would like to concatenate it. The only way to have the text justified is to consider it as a new paragraph, which I want to avoid.

Here is the Javascript function (it could be better, I know)

```
    function showHide(mytext) {
     if (document.getElementById('mytext1')) {
            if (document.getElementById('mytext1' + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
                document.getElementById('mytext1' + '-show').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mytext1').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('mytext1').style.textAlign ='justify';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('mytext1' + '-show').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('mytext1').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

}
```

Here is some HTML

```
     <p class="NeueLite text-justify"> Beginning of the text.<a id="mytext1-show" onclick="showHide('mytext1'); return false;" class ="abstract"> More</a>
               <div id="mytext1" style="display: none;" class="moretext">
    Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.Hidden/shown text.
 <a id="mytext1-hide"  onclick="showHide('mytext1');return false;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="abstract" >Less</a></p></div>
```

And the classes of my CSS :

```
div.moretext {
   font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
      line-height: 1.2 !important;
      font-size: 0.8rem !important;
      text-align: justify !important;
      }
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to answer your question if you put your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you put the hidden text in a `<div>`. Use a `<span>` instead. Also, put the `text-align: justify;` in the `<p>`.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9PWAv/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I have strictly copied the code, but the hide link doesn't seem to work. Is there anything I should write after the query you added ? I have another function just after that...

Comment: @coralie you probably shouldn't copy the `document.queryselector(...)` thing, I only put it there because `onclick=" ... "` doesn't seem to work on jsfiddle.

Comment: @coralie or you can keep the `document.queryselector(...)`, but remove `onclick=" ... "` from the hide link.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I had to use the .query to get the onclick work too. Thank you so very much!